Cut / Paste not removing data from origin spreadsheet
Monthly for the past many years, I move a small table of data from a series of 15 spreadsheets I open all at once, and compile into one spreadsheet.  I normally do this with cut / paste, and in the past, cut removed the data from the origin spreadsheet, and that made it easy as I'm alt/tabbing to know which origin spreadsheet I haven't moved the data from yet.
Today, cut is not erasing the data.  It does leave it encircled so I know that I have moved it to the master spreadsheet.   This worked a month ago.

Does this issue occur with other workbooks? You may create a new one, do a test.
